# Jquery Custom Validation not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, validation

I am in a situation where I cant use the validate plugin of Jquery.
So I have written a custom validator. But the test function is not working for some reason.

Code is running fine till the line  `if (format.test(email)) {` . Please share your knowledge. Thanks in advance

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#MainContent_btnSubmit").click(function () {
        validateEmail();

    });
});






function validateEmail() {

    var format = "[a-zA-Z._0-9]@[a-zA-Z.0-9].[a-zA-Z]";
    var email = $("#MainContent_txtEmail").val();


    if (format.test(email)) {
        alert("Correct Email");
    }
    else {
        alert("Wrong Email");
    }
```

Comment: what is the error logged in firebug

Comment: Thank You for all your answers :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`format` needs to be a `RegExp` object:

```
var format = new RegExp("[a-zA-Z._0-9]@[a-zA-Z.0-9].[a-zA-Z]");
```

Additionally, I suspect you want the value to contain nothing but an email, so use anchors:

```
var format = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z._0-9]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\\.[a-zA-Z]+$");
```

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, regexes are not written as strings. They have their own literal type:

```
var format = /[a-zA-Z._0-9]@[a-zA-Z.0-9].[a-zA-Z]/;
```

Secondly, every character class matches only a single character. And a `.` is a wildcard if not escaped. Also, `test` will report true if any substring of `email` fulfills the pattern. So you need to [anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) the pattern. You probably meant something like this:

```
var format = /^[a-zA-Z._0-9]+@[a-zA-Z.0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z]+$/;
```

Thirdly, [matching valid email addresses is harder than you think.](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the regex `"^[a-zA-Z._0-9]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\\.[a-zA-Z]+$"` and create a RegExp Object with it

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is a copy paste error, but looking at you function code, one can see that you haven't closed the function `validateEmail()`

Comment: That still won't help, because `string`s don't have a `test` method.

Comment: @m.buettner: off course you are alright. the regex in also wrong at the second place

Comment: Yes it is. Also, since the OP said it's running fine until the `if` statement, I believe that the missing `}` is probably a copy-paste error.

Answer (score 0):

i think you are either missing the jquery plugin at the top like this:

```
<script src='path-to-your-jQuery-plugin' type='text/javascript'></script>
```

or

```
function validateEmail() {

var format = /^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$/;
var email = $("#MainContent_txtEmail").val();


    if (format.test(email)) {
        alert("Correct Email");
    }
    else {
        alert("Wrong Email");
    }
}    // in your code here you missed the closing tag of the function
```

Comment: That still won't help, because `string`s don't have a `test` method.